# How to fix RVM gems "[ missing bin/ruby ]"

Tags: ruby, rvm

After executing `rvm list` I get following output:

```
rvm rubies

   gems [ missing bin/ruby ]
=* ruby-2.0.0-p645 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.6 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.2.1 [ x86_64 ]
```

What does `gems [ missing bin/ruby ]` mean?

Is `gems` some kind of system gemset? It wasn't created by me and I don't know if I can, or should, remove it.

Answer (score 16):

After I ran:

```
rvm fix-permissions
```

I was then able to uninstall versions that had `[ missing bin/ruby ]`.

Comment: I've been wrestling with this for 2 hours...this is the first and only thing to help me.  :)

Answer (score 6):

You probably installed RVM using:

```
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby .
```

Uninstall RVM using:

```
rvm implode
```

Once uninstalled, reinstall it using:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

I had the same problem and that fixed it.

Comment: I have no option to try this solution but it looks promising. This is strange that recommended by https://rvm.io/rvm/install code (`curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`) adds this `gems` gemset maybe it's there for some reason?