# How to fix list of [ missing bin/ruby ] in RVM gemsets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

After executing `rvm list gemsets` on my macOS system I got the following output:

```
rvm gemsets

    ruby-2.6.5@esy_key [ missing bin/ruby ]
    ruby-2.6.5@ezekey [ missing bin/ruby ]
    ruby-2.6.5@global [ missing bin/ruby ]
    ruby-2.6.5@red_search [ missing bin/ruby ]
    ruby-2.6.5@reddoorz_uat [ missing bin/ruby ]
```

What does `[ missing bin/ruby ]` mean?

When I run `rvm use 'ruby-2.6.5@reddoorz_uat'` and after `bundle install` returns the error message:

```
bash: /Users/commeasure/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin/bundle: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RVM gems \[ missing bin/ruby \]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29876386/rvm-gems-missing-bin-ruby)

Comment: I tried but not worked for me. :(